# How do I show my domain in the address bar instead of the actual location?

Tags: url, domain-name

I just bought a domain, "example.com" for illustration.
I have hosting on "hosting.be/myname". When someone visits example.com, the addressbar changes automatically to hosting.be/myname.

Is there any way to keep my domain name, 'example.com' in the address bar?

I'm very sorry, but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting company should have provided you with at least 2 nameservers. You can use these nameservers on your registrar's website to point your domain at.

You may need to contact your host's customer support for this information but it can usually be found on the forums or FAQ. When you sign up for hosting, sometimes you need to enter your domain name up front for proper configuration. Your host should be able to sort this out for you however, if you forgot to configure it initially.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the hosting came free with my ISP connection, so I'm assuming it differs from hosting you order and pay for.

Comment: Well, you did have to pay the ISP in order to get the (free) hosting, so they should offer you support for it. I'd call up the ISP and ask them if they can provide you with the correct nameservers for their webservers. @joon

Comment: In my experience, the hosting you get from your ISP will not let you use their nameservers.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me too, as they are reluctant to do anything at all (but I contacted them anyway). So theoretically, if I were to order hosting with an actual hosting firm, they'd offer me a way to achieve this? It has nothing to do with the actual domain registration? (pardon my ignorance)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this easy if you have access to cpanel if you have, try an alias domain, but you have to do the setup needed for the domain ^points to the correct location; if you need help with that, there is a lot of info about it